# comparacion de dos elementos de una lista zip usando lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Quiero comparar los elementos de una lista zipeada de dos listas para saber si son mayores usando lambda.

`compare=lambda ledzip: ledzip for e,c in zip(list1,list2)print("True")if e in ledzep > c else print("False") print(compare)`

Comment: creería que tendrías que explayarte un poco mas y organizar el código que pusiste. Honestamente no lo entiendo. la pregunta es: ¿queres ir comparando elemento a elemento y que eso te devuelva una lista con "True" o "False" dependiendo de si el primero es mayor al segundo?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que se quiere es obtener una lista en la que tengamos un valor de verdad (es decir True o False) dependiendo de la comparación del primer elemento con el segundo de una lista zipeada:

La respuesta es:

```
 compare = lambda l1,l2: [True  if (e[0] > e[1]) else False for e in list(zip(l1,l2))  ]
```

se pueden crear dos listas de ejemplo:

```
list1 = [1, 5, 3]
list2 = [2, 1, 2]
```

luego ejecutar la función:

```
>>> compare(list1,list2)
[False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Si se usa `lambda` lo lógico sería usarla junto a `map` en el contexto de programación funcional:

```
lista1 = [3, 11, 13, 17]
lista2 = [5, 2, 7, 23]

compare = list(map(lambda items: items[0] > items[1], zip(lista1, lista2)))
```

Si usas un ciclo `for`, entonces una lista por compresión es más legible, simple e incluso eficiente:

```
lista1 = [3, 11, 13, 17]
lista2 = [5, 2, 7, 23]

compare = [a > b for a, b in zip(lista1, lista2)]
```

En ambos casos:

> ```
> >>> compare
> [False, True, True, False]
> ```